# Why would this create an endless loop and crash my browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

Trying to create a method that will count the amount of matching elements between a start and end element. Nothing too wild. Turns out those two console.log's I have in the middle identifying `next_item` and `end_elem` crash my browser in an endless loop. Ideally I'm trying to have that within the while loop call so that I can prevent it from going past the `end_elem` once it catches it by doing `next_item.index() < end_elem.index()`, but that evidently destroys my browser everytime. I have no idea why.

```
  find_the_count_of_elements_between_two_elements: function(class_to_count, start_elem, end_elem) {
    var number_of_times = 0;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 1;
    next_item = start_elem.nextAll().slice(start, end);

    while ( start < 6 ) {

      // console.log(next_item.index() < end_elem.index() );
      console.log("next_item : " + next_item.index() );
      console.log("end_elem : " + end_elem.index());

      if ( next_item.hasClass(class_to_count) ) {
        number_of_times++;
      };

      start++;
      end++;
      next_item = start_elem.nextAll().slice(start, end);
      console.log(next_item);
    };
    return number_of_times;
  },
```

Comment: on a sidenote, have you considered [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the logs/console output as well (Cleanse them if necessary).

Comment: Any reason *next_item* isn't declared local?

Comment: Just a question : why ";" after the "if (){}" and after the "while(){}" ?

Comment: @Yoshi, good point. I'll try that.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, could you unpack that comment? I don't understand.

Comment: @Ricola3D Sure. Couldn't hurt to remove them. Can it hurt to include them?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I think you got the correct answer. Assuming that using the `var`, it is then declared "local". Otherwise its "something else" that crashes my browser :(

Comment: @Trip Yes, I meant using *var* to declare it.

Comment: Well that was the answer Joachim. Huge thanks. Please make it an answer so I can set it as correct! My obeisance if you could describe why that made it fail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring JQuery objects as global (ie without `var`) seems to confuse certain browsers, so it's always a good idea to declare them local to your functions.

Note: I'm glad this information helped, but if someone can actually explain **why** this happens, they deserve the solution mark, not I.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your function find_the_count_of_elements_between_two_elements only can work for siblings. That's because you use ..index() to determine the element's position in the DOM - relative to its siblings.

In that case you can achieve the same goal much cheaper. I will use filter instead of class_to_count as it is more generic.

```
function count_matching_elements_between(filter, start_elem, end_elem) {
    return $(start_elem).nextAll(filter).filter($(end_elem).prevAll()).length;
}
```

To find your elements with a specific class you can use:

```
count_matching_elements_between('.myClass', '#myStart', '#myEnd');
```

or provide explicit DOM nodes or jQuery selections as start and end.

BTW: Did you edit your code example?
I don't see any "if (next_item.index() < end_elem.index())" there.

Comment: Also did not edit it. I have it as a `console.log` that I removed from the while statement and was attempting to derive it as a log figuring I might be able to produce it safely that way.